# excel remove duplicate sum method

Tags: excel, match, countif

I have a spreadsheet whereby I am trying sum the a total. I have done this but this is where I require support as I need to get an average for the values in a range. The spreadsheet adds a 1 to the accepted value. The problem I am facing is when a same value is added it counts 2 same instances found. When trying to get the average this will skew my results. How can I avoid this?  Please help

[image: Spreadsheet Illustration]

Answer (score 0):

Try an Advanced Filter with Unique Records Only. This should do the trick.

Go to your `Data` tab on the ribbon, in the `Sort & Filter` section click `Advanced`. The `List Range` is your range you want to filter (this should be the entire range, not just the range of `AgentName` since it looks like each `AgentName` can have multiple `Outcomes`), check the `Unique Records Only` box.

Now you should have that list with just unique names, so nothing is duplicated; now you can use `=SUM(E:E)` and `=AVERAGE(E:E)` to get the calculations you need without them being skewed (assuming your data is in Column E).

Comment: Because his question specifically addresses deleting the duplicates. In the picture: `I want to be able to delete instances like these` and in the question: `The problem I am facing is when a same value is added it counts 2 same instances found. When trying to get the average this will skew my results. How can I avoid this?` He obviously knows how to use the `SUM` and `AVERAGE` functions. But if you want to be that petty about the downvote I gave you earlier I'll edit my answer.